# Python gives unicode error when writing to file

Tags: python-3.x, file, unicode, io

I'm trying to write to a file.

```
filename = "test.txt"
string = "Niñas and niños"

with open(filename, 'w') as element:
            element.write(string)
```

This returns the following error:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alex/Documents/Python/filewriter.py", line 5, in <module>
    element.write(string)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xf1' 
in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)"
```

I am using the latest version of Python, latest version of MacOS, and SublimeText3 as my editor.

Anyone have an idea what's going on?

Comment: Your code works fine for me as-is (Python 3.6.1 on MacOS). Do you have unusual environment variables set on your system with respect to encoding? I have none set, and you shouldn't need them. You also shouldn't need PYTHONIOENCODING if you are handling encoding/decoding correctly in your software (I would advise against that crutch).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Open the file with utf-8 encoding, like this:

```
with open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as element:
```

Comment: Works brilliantly! Thanks!